# Código funciona no console, mas quando chamo ele no documento não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um código que funciona perfeitamente executando no console, mas não funciona quando chamo ele clicando em um botão do documento.

**Função do meu código:** Ler um arquivo *.csv* e separar palavras entre ponto e vírgula.

**Retorno testando no console:** Todas as frases separadas em um array: *produto[0,15:"Referencia", 0,16:"Modelagem",...]*

**Retorno clicando no botão:** *produto[0,15:undefined, 0,16:undefined,...]*

Para fins de teste, no documento .csv que estou subindo contém estes dados (*estes 15 ponto e vírgula no começo é porque a separação no **for** inicia no index 15*):

> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;REFERÊNCIA;MODELAGEM;GRADE;grade1;grade2;grade3;grade4;grade5;grade6;grade7;grade8;grade9;grade10;ATACADO R$;VAREJO

**Meu código:**

```js
function ImportarProdutos()
{

//Pega elemento <input>
var file = document.getElementById("DadosCsv");

///Variavel para ler arquivo (.csv)
var reader = new FileReader();
//Lê o arquivo
reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);

//adiciona o que foi lido em uma variavel
var produtos = reader.result;

var produto = [];

//Aqui apenas separa cada palavra
var pos =30;
var j = 15;

for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

  for( ; j < pos; j++){
  

    produto[[i,j]] = produtos.split(";")[j];
    
  }
pos = pos+15;
 
}

console.log(produto);
}
```

```html
     <input type="file" id="DadosCsv" />
     <button onclick="ImportarProdutos()">Importar Produtos</button>
```

Comment: Colando o código que está dentro da função, e removendo a palavra 'var' antes das variáveis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está querendo manipular o conteúdo do arquivo antes dele ter sido lido devido isso ser um processo assíncrono. No console você consegue porque já deu tempo do arquivo ser lido.

Use o evento `onload` para só tratar o conteúdo após o arquivo ter sido lido:

```
function ImportarProdutos(){
   //Pega elemento <input>
   var file = document.getElementById("DadosCsv");
   ///Variavel para ler arquivo (.csv)
   var reader = new FileReader();
   //Lê o arquivo
   reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
   reader.onload = function () {
      var produtos = reader.result;

      //adiciona o que foi lido em uma variavel
      var produto = [];

      //Aqui apenas separa cada palavra
      var pos =30;
      var j = 15;

      teste = produtos.split(";")

      for( i = 0; i < 3; i++){

         for( ; j < pos; j++){
            produto[[i,j]] = produtos.split(";")[j];
         }
         pos = pos+15;
      }

      console.log(produto);
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, isso me ajudou muito, funcionou perfeitamente! Seguindo sua solução, usei o 'Onloadend'.